# WordPress Twenty Thirteen make sidebar not to change footer

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, footer, sidebar

Most of all have seen Twenty Thirteen WordPress theme that is cool. By default footer has 3 columns but when I place widget on sidebar, in footer appears fourth column. I read that it is not BUG and everything is working just fine, but I need that **columns on footer always stayed the same**. If widgets on sidebar is very high and overlaps to footer it should be better to change the height of the page not numbers of columns on footer. So I don't know how to achieve this and can you please help me?

P.S.
 *Sorry for my English skills.*

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the solution you are looking for: http://www.bnewton.co.uk/blog/how-to-prevent-the-sidebar-widgets-from-overlapping-the-footer-comments-section-on-websites-using-wordpress/

This will hide widgets if they overlap the footer or comments section on your wordpress site.